# Get the publish date of the older post inside a tag

Tags: tags

What would it be the best approach to get the publish date of the oldest post inside current `tag`?

Answer (score 0):

To get the publish date to each post via the template tag [`get_the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/). However, this works only inside [the Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). I'm understanding what you mean with 'inside current tag'. But the tag is an additional meta value to the post type, via taxonomy and is without dependent to the post date.